# Angular 2 structural directive with service call

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I created a structural directive to check if a user have some permissions. The permission is fetch from backend and save in the service itself. The structural directive injects the service per DI and should check if the permission exists in the service or not.

The idea : the service should fetch all permission from backend -> check permission through directive -> render if its true

The problem is that the service does not fetch the service. The service waits until all query from structural directive, then start fetch the service.

It looks something like this:

**authority.directive.ts**

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[authority]'
})

export class AuthorityDirective {
  constructor(private userService: UserService,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef < any > ,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) {}

  @Input() set bdAuthority(authName: string) {
    if (this.userService.hasAuthority(authName)) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      return;
    }
    this.viewContainer.clear();
    return;

  }
}
```

and the **authority.service.ts** like this

```js
    // check if the current user has the defined privilege
    public hasAuthority(authorityName: string): boolean {
      return (
        this.authorityCache
        .filter((authority) => {
          return authorityName === authority.name
        })
        .length) > 0;
    }

    public onBrowserReload(tempUser: User) {
      this.getUserById(tempUser.id).subscribe(user => {
        this.updatePrivilegesAndUser(user);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Is there anyway to make the service starts earlier?

Comment: FYI structural directives are meant to alter the DOM like *ngIf and *ngFor

Comment: does it make difference in rendering sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the last response I gave myself the task to investigate and came up with a solution for a similar problem.

I have to refresh an array of permissions from a backend endpoint, with this array in an structural directive I determine if the element can be seen by the user, I was approaching the solution with your same code, and had the same error, the permissions array call to the backend wasn't refreshing the array fast enough, so the solution was to use and AsyncSubject. An AsyncSubject will resolve in a value once the call is made, so you can return it from a method.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, AsyncSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PermissionsService {

  baseUrl = '/apiURL/v5';
  permissionsSubject = new AsyncSubject;
  hasPermissions = false;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  async updatePermissions(clientId, roleName) {
    const response = await this.http.get(this.getRoleUrl(clientId, roleName)).toPromise();
    this.permissionsSubject.next(response['permissions'] || []);
    this.permissionsSubject.complete(); // Once I finish sending the value that I need i end the subject to propagate its value to all the subscribers.
  }

  getRoleUrl(clientId, roleName) {
    return `${this.baseUrl}/client/${clientId}/roles/${roleName}`;
  }

  setCachedPermissions(permissions) {
    this.permissionsSubject.next(permissions);
  }

  getCachedPermissions() {
    return this.permissionsSubject.asObservable();
  }
   // This is the method used by the structural directive to determine if the object is rendered
  cacheHasPermission(slug) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.getCachedPermissions().subscribe((permissions: String[]) => {
        resolve(permissions.includes(slug));
      });
    });
  }
}
```